# JavaScript replace not removing the whitespace

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the space in postcode's. I have tested the `replace()` in the console and it works, but it does not work stepping through it in debug with chrome.

Is there another way to get this to work?

```
 $('#search_postcode').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getPostcode = $('#txt_search').val();

    var postcode = {};
    if (getPostcode !== "") {

        var str = getPostcode;
        str.replace(/\s+/g,'');

        if (str.length === 7) {
            postcode.Outward = str.substr(0, 4);
            postcode.Inward = str.substr(4, 3);
        }
        if (str.length === 6) {
            postcode.Outward = str.substr(0, 3);
            postcode.Inward = str.substr(3, 3);
        }

        console.log(postcode);
```

It always comes back with the space in `str`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string, it doesn't change the passed one (strings are immutable in JavaScript).

Use

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g,'');
```